# JetBrains WebStorm - Setting up Debug Console to show Shortcut/Hyperlink

Tags: webstorm

I am trying to debug a static HTML with JavaScript using JetBrains WebStorm.

```
JetBrains WebStorm Console window with error in it.
```

[image: Example in Webstorm]

WebStorm's Debug Console is very dull (not colourful) as well it does not give me the specific location of the error.

```
Chrome Console window with the same error in it.
```

[image: Example in Chrome]
.

Chrome's Debug Console shows **error with hyperlink to the problematic code lines.**

I find it very useful when I was debugging with Chrome.

It seems like WebStorm's Debug Console isn't very well-defined as chrome (or other browsers').

**Is there any settings that can allow it to provide proper hyperlink instead of saying anonymous function?**

Comment: @Rob Thank you for the reply. I thought the question is related to "rendering issue" in particular software other than text/codes issue. I believe image is the best way to describe this issue. Please correct me if I am wrong if so, I will remove pictures and describe as much as I can with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if you are using some outdated IDE version... The debugger interactive console available since 2019.1 supports colors and navigation, see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/03/webstorm-2019-1/#debugger

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply, it's good to know that they've added interactive console since 2019.1 version. My Web-storm is 2017 and I should consider upgrading as this feature makes debugging a lot easier.